# Packaging a Compose Multiplatform project as a library

Tags: android, ios, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, compose-multiplatform

I am interested to understand if we can develop a particular page of the app in Compose Multiplatform, package it as a library/bundle and include it in the existing Android and iOS app projects for consumption (similar to React Native)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but only if you are using Compose for iOS(it's not stable yet Jun 2023). A component written in Composer for iOS can be integrated into a native iOS application.

For more info checkout this presentation: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FWVi4aV36d8

and blog post "Interoperability with SwiftUI and UIKit views": https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2023/05/compose-multiplatform-for-ios-is-in-alpha/#InteroperabilitywithSwiftUIandUIKitviews